# How to set light text on the light background in the status bar (hybrid app)

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to set the *textColorPrimary* of my app white and *colorPrimary* yellow. I'm working on a hybrid app and the official cordova plugin (*cordova-plugin-statusbar*) allows me only to change color of the *colorPrimaryDark* `<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#feb900" />` and to define that *textColorPrimary* is either white or black according to the *colorPrimary* `<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />` If it's light then the text is going to be black and the other way. I couldn't specify the color of *colorPrimary* using this plugin so I took this one: *cordova-plugin-headercolor* from npm. And I added `<preference name="HeaderColor" value="#feb900" />`. I specified my *colorPrimary* to be yellow but yellow is more light than dark so my *textColorPrimary* turned black. And now I would like to know if there is any way to specify my *colorPrimary* yellow and *textColorPrimary* white? I used the oficial names from android coding terminology because of this picture. [image]

Comment: Just change the hex values of colorPrimary and textColorPrimary to yellow's hex and white's hex in your values/colors.xml file

Comment: Could you help me to find it? https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar